# Converting Formula to Text

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code below:

```
Dim rng1 As range, _
    i As Long, _
    col1 As String, _
    col2 As String, _
    col3 As String, _
    count1 As Integer, _
    count2 As Integer, _
    count3 As Integer

    col1 = Sheet4.range("D7").Value
    col2 = Sheet4.range("D9").Value
    col3 = "A"
    count3 = 2

    For i = 3 To 13299
    Set rng1 = Sheet2.range(col1 & i)
        If Sheet3.range(col2 & i) = Sheet2.range(col1 & i) Or _
            Sheet3.range(col2 & i).Value = "NULL" And Sheet2.range(col1 & i) = "" Then
            Sheet4.range("B" & i).Value = "Match"
            count1 = count1 + 1

            ElseIf Sheet3.range(col2 & i).Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText = False _
            And Sheet2.range(col1 & i).Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText = False Then
            ---Insert here

            Else
```

What code should I put in the "Insert here" part to convert a formula into text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where what you're trying to convert to a value, but say you are trying to convert whatever is in A1 to a value you can use:

```
Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value
```

Comment: I want that a formula like this =+My Name to be converted as a string. Is there a code to do that?

Comment: Do you want to replace the formula with a string in a particular cell? The above line will do that.

Comment: get the formula of the cell and convert it to a string:
"var cellFormula as String"    "cellFormula = CStr(Cell(1,1).formulaR1C1)"

Comment: @beginner_pr glad it worked for you. Do you mind giving it a +1 and marking it as answered? Thanks.